# Wordpress plugin, do not prepend host in wp_register_script

Tags: wordpress

I am pretty new to WP and have a little question about the wp_register_script function,.

I have a dev environment where the url is test.example.com .. right know when i make a plugin and use wordpress wp_register_script to insert the .js and .css files wordpress prepend the host in front of the url ..

Is there a good way to handle this?? without creating a test DB and change the "siteurl" ?

Comment: That's the point of using `wp_register_script()`. It will output the absolute URI. That host name will automatically change when you migrate hosts.

Comment: Humm, but how can I then have a "dev env" where i want to test my plugin etc. before it goes live - on a test domain link test.example.com with a live DB pointing all urls to example.com ? hope i make sense?

Comment: Can you post your code? It would make it easier to help you.

Comment: if ( !wp_script_is( $this->tag, 'enqueued' ) ) {
    wp_register_script(
     $this->tag,
     plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ). '/js/playlist.js',
     array('jquery'),
     $this->version,
     true
    );
   }

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for my issue ..

I could set WP_SITEURL in the we-config.php file (not the best solution)

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "test.example.com") {
   define('WP_SITEURL','http://test.example.com'); // use this if we are testing on test.skala.fm (not localhost)

   define('ENVIRONMENT', 'local'); // using localdb
   //define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production'); // use this if we are testing on test.example.com (not localhost)
} else {
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
}
```